# 3-D Shape detection from triangulation mesh

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, pattern-recognition, triangulation

I'm looking for any algorithm or source code which can find whole or partial simple 3-D shapes (sphere, cylinder, cone, etc) in a 3-D triangulation mesh.

I've found several papers on algorithms (for example see [this PDF](http://zugspitze.cs.uni-bonn.de/docs/publications/2006/cg-2006-2.pdf)) which can find shapes in point clouds. A triangulation can easily be converted to a point cloud, but it seems to me that it should be easier to find shapes if you already have a triangulation, as you have more information about the surface to be matched--connectivity is lost for example in the conversion to a point cloud.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The point cloud to shape mapping problem is difficult (read difficult *open problem*). If you know math, given a mesh, you can compute the homology of the mesh and see if you find something useful.

Comment: The phd thesis of a friend of mine can be relevant to what you want. You need a quite strong math background to read it: http://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00443038/

Comment: This is a difficult thing to do in 2d ...

Comment: @Alexandre, Thanks--the read was no problem, understanding, not so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Princeton Shape Retreival and Analysis Group](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/gfx/proj/shape/) are the guru's in this area. You can trace the feild using their publications.